# OpenShift superuser permissions

Tags: openshift

I am trying to install Client tools on RHEL/OpenShift free server. However following https://developers.openshift.com/en/getting-started-rhel-centos.html#client-tools I am supposed to execute some super user commands which gives a permission error. Do I need to do something to enable super user access on my virtual machine?

> sudo su

```
bash: /usr/bin/sudo: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 3):

OpenShift Online does not allow you to gain super user access, so I don't think you will be able to install the client tools on your OpenShift servers. The OpenShift client tools (rhc) aren't meant to be installed on your OpenShift servers, they are meant to be installed on your local computer.

Comment: The only reason I needed those is to avoid making a ssh tunnel for external access to MySql. Do you maybe know how I can enable port forwarding?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are saying, since "port forwarding" and "ssh tunneling" are two terms for the exact same thing. If you need to use port forwarding to access your OpenShift MySQL instance from your local computer, then install the `rhc` tool on your local computer and run the `rhc port-forward` command. https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-port-forwarding.html